# export 'useEffect' (imported as 'useEffect') was not found in 'react' (module has no exports)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am receiving errors of:

[image]

It seems to be errors related with redux and react redux:

I also have a warning of:

```
Attempted import error: 'useMemo' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'useMemo').
LOG from webpack.FileSystemInfo
<w> Managed item C:\Users\Bernadette Kotelo\Documents\Gahn Eden\frontend\node_modules\react-redux\node_modules\@babel\runtime isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
+ 11 hidden lines
```

Here's my package.json inside my react redux folder in node_modules:

```
{
  "name": "react-redux",
  "version": "8.0.2",
  "description": "Official React bindings for Redux",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "reactjs",
    "redux"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Dan Abramov <dan.abramov@me.com> (https://github.com/gaearon)",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux",
  "repository": "github:reduxjs/react-redux",
  "bugs": "https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues",
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "types": "./es/index.d.ts",
  "unpkg": "dist/react-redux.js",
  "module": "es/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "lib",
    "src",
    "es"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build:commonjs": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=commonjs babel src --extensions \".js,.ts,.tsx\" --out-dir lib",
    "build:es": "babel src --extensions \".js,.ts,.tsx\" --out-dir es",
    "build:umd": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development rollup -c -o dist/react-redux.js",
    "build:umd:min": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production rollup -c -o dist/react-redux.min.js",
    "build:types": "tsc",
    "build": "yarn build:types && yarn build:commonjs && yarn build:es && yarn build:umd && yarn build:umd:min",
    "clean": "rimraf lib dist es coverage",
    "api-types": "api-extractor run --local",
    "format": "prettier --write \"{src,test}/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}\" \"docs/**/*.md\"",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx,js test/utils test/components test/hooks",
    "prepare": "yarn clean && yarn build",
    "pretest": "yarn lint",
    "test": "jest",
    "type-tests": "yarn tsc -p test/typetests/tsconfig.json",
    "coverage": "codecov"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0",
    "react": "^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0",
    "react-native": ">=0.59",
    "redux": "^4"
  },
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "@types/react": {
      "optional": true
    },
    "@types/react-dom": {
      "optional": true
    },
    "react-dom": {
      "optional": true
    },
    "react-native": {
      "optional": true
    },
    "redux": {
      "optional": true
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/use-sync-external-store": "^0.0.3",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
    "react-is": "^18.0.0",
    "use-sync-external-store": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.14.5",
    "@microsoft/api-extractor": "^7.18.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.2.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^15.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^9.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^2.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^3.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-12": "npm:@testing-library/react@^12",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^3.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/object-assign": "^4.0.30",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/react-is": "^17",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.1",
    "codecov": "^3.8.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "jest": "^26.6.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-17": "npm:react@^17",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom-17": "npm:react-dom@^17",
    "react-native": "^0.64.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer-17": "npm:react-test-renderer@^17",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.32.1",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.6",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4"
  }
}
```

And heres is my main app package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.0.9",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.3.2",
    "@chakra-ui/system": "^2.2.9",
    "@chakra-ui/theme-tools": "^2.0.11",
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.10.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@hypertheme-editor/chakra-ui": "^0.2.0-dev.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.5",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "^5.10.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "chroma-js": "^2.4.2",
    "framer-motion": "^7.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "primeflex": "^3.2.1",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primereact": "^8.4.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-calendar": "^3.8.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
    "react-custom-scrollbars-2": "^4.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.2",
    "react-github-btn": "^1.4.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-is": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.54.9",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "stylis": "^4.1.2",
    "stylis-plugin-rtl": "^2.0.2",
    "swiper": "^8.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried uninstalling redux and react-redux and installing them again. It failed.
The errors say all my react hooks cannot be imported in react, inside my node_mudules/react-redux folder. Which is confusing because I have react installed.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Are you using `Typescript` ? which version are you using ?

Comment: I am using Javascript

Comment: could you show how you're importing these hooks (add your component where you import them ) ?

Comment: So I am using Javascript to develop  my MERN app. I had installed react-redux and redux in my frontend. Then my error pointed  inside my node_modules folder inside the react-redux folder that came when i installed react-redux. Some files in there are made out of typescript and others javascript. Heres how they import their useMemo and other hooks: import {useMemo} from 'react'

Comment: But I have recently tried uninstalling react-redux and redux again and deleting the react-redux folder in my node_modules folder. I stopped my react server and tried to install them again. Than ran my react server again. And this time it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this issue. I deleted my node_modules folder `rm -rf node_modules/` and ran `npm i`, and the issue was fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but  I fixed the problem a few months ago. But your answer is helpful I will accept it